# For-loop, append, and += increment operator

Tags: python, loops, append

```
a=[]
a.append(0)
a.append(0)
print(a)
for i in a:
    i+=1
print(a)
```

I think it should print `[0,0] [1,1]` but it prints `[0,0] [0,0]`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `for i in a`, in each iteration you're assigning an element of `a` to a variable named `i`, and when you do an operation on `i`, the changes won't be applied to elements of `a`. Try:

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    a[i] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you are changing the value of `i` and that's not changing the elements of the list `a`.
if you want to change the value of the elements of that list, you can do:

```
a=[]
a.append(0)
a.append(0)
print(a)

for index, element in enumerate(a):
    element+=1
    a[index] = element

print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the value of each element in `a` instead of the value of `i` because this is not changing the elements of `a`. To change each element on `a` you can do:

```
a = [0,0]
print(a) # [0,0]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] += 1
print(a) # [1,1]
```

or using the function `enumerate()` if you want to iterate over the list instead of the range:

```
a = [0,0]
print(a) # [0,0]
for index, _ in enumerate(a):
    a[index] += 1
print(a) # [1,1]
```